# Identify this convertible car from Man in the High Castle

Tags: the-man-in-the-high-castle

In The second season of Man in the High Castle Episode 6 'Kintsugi', a convertible car is driven by Nicole Becker.

Can anyone identify this car:

[image]

One of the more curious features of this car is that the doors slide into the body which I've never seen before on a convertible:

[image]

I'm not after a ridiculously accurate answer, model and make would suffice but if you can provide more information that'd be great.

Due to the exotic design of this car it's possible it was made for the show but I could be wrong

Comment: For all your "movie vehicle" related questions, I also recommend another site which hasn't been listed on this page, imcdb.org. The car you're looking for is there: http://www.imcdb.org/movie_1740299-The-Man-in-the-High-Castle.html

Comment: I'd also add that IMFDB is the database for all firearms and weapons used in films.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This looks like the [Kaiser Darrin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaiser_Darrin), circa 1954.

There is a nice piece on MyCarQuest regarding [this car and the concept of sliding door design](http://mycarquest.com/2015/04/why-didnt-the-sliding-doors-of-the-kaiser-darrin-catch-on.html).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaiser_Darrin#/media/File:1954_Kaiser_Darrin_dash.jpg

From Wikipedia:

> Along with Darrin's trademark fender line, the Kaiser Darrin had entry doors that, instead of being hinged to open outward, slid on tracks into the front fender wells behind the front wheels. Fueled by Darrin's dislike for conventional doors, the designer had taken out a patent on the sliding auto door concept in 1946.[7] To keep the door assembly as simple as possible, no side windows were built into them.[3] The car was equipped with a three-position Landau top, which was also considered novel, and the design on the whole considered by industry critics and writers as beautifully proportioned. The only flaw was considered the car's front grille. High and shell-shaped, it looked as though the automobile "wanted to give you a kiss," as one writer commented.

Comment: I was wondering if it was a Darrin! Nice find!

Comment: Fantastic, this bugged me for a while and I wasn't sure how to find the answer

Comment: That's exactly what it was. In the third eposide of that season, you can see the character get in the car and drive away, where you get a clear view of the rear of the car, complete with the name on the trunk lid, similar to this: https://stevemckelvie.files.wordpress.com/2012/07/kaiser-darrin-1954-12.jpg

Answer (score 1):

It's a 1954 Kaiser Darrin. The pocket doors are unique.  It was also the first all fiberglass car, body built by Glastron.  That particular car is housed at the LeMay Family Collection in Tacoma WA.

Comment: Wikipedia claims this [Glasspar G2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glasspar_G2) was the first all fiberglass body, this was built in 1950

Answer (score 0):

I wondered if it was possibly a reproduction of the Kaiser Darrin. See all these other vehicles in the show that are either new or just 5 to 10 years old, when you get to close ups of people inside the vehicle, the steering wheels are inevitably cracked, giving away that these vehicles are 55 years old at the newest. Not so with the Darrin, at s2 e6 right at the 15 minute mark there is a very clean shot of the interior, the steering wheel, leather, everything looks new. So either this was a truly fabulous restoration done recently or a replica.

Comment: What does this add to the existing answer?